# Excel formula highest value with condition

Tags: excel, formula

I have a table containing PriceList (As Text), Model and Price. The list is sorted by PriceList descending. Example

```
PriceList Model Price
0740      A     10
0740      B     20
0740      C     30
0735      A     9
0735      B     19
0735      C     29
0731      A     8
0731      B     18
0731      C     28
0731      D     38
```

As you can see, Model D was discontinued with PriceList 0732.
I need a formula that gives me the following

```
Requested   Relevant    Latest
PriceList   Model       PriceList
                        Available
0735         A          0735           
0735         B          0735
0735         C          0735
0735         D          0731
```

I need the formula for the Last Pricelist Available column. The formula should do the following: If the requested PriceList exists for the relevant Model write it to the field IF NOT give back the latest price list which contains the model which is <= the Requesed price list.

I found a solution to do that with a Matrix formula - which performs quite bad. Is there a way WITHOUT using matrix formulas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we need to do is make the PriceList less than the requested value when it doesn't match. The easiest way to do this is make the value Zero

The 2nd table I put into A15:C19

First we need to construct the comparisons within the MAX formula:

```
=MAX($A$2:$A$11*$B$2:$B$11=B16*$A$2:$A$11<=A16)
```

next we need to convert all the TRUE/FALSE into 0/1 for multiplying:

```
=MAX($A$2:$A$11*--($B$2:$B$11=B16)*--($A$2:$A$11<=A16))
```

Finally, we need to let the function return an array to get a single value from, by entering the function as an array formula with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. You know it's entered correctly when Excel *(not you)* puts curly braces around the formula:

```
{=MAX($A$2:$A$11*--($B$2:$B$11=B16)*--($A$2:$A$11<=A16))}
```